# Get another child of a grid from a known child in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I am having a four grids each with a Button and the ListView like

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">
     <ListView .....
     </ListView>
</Grid>
```

All the buttons present calls the same event "ButtonBase_OnClick". My challenge is how can I get the ListView object of the button which is in the same grid as the button on which click event is generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse the tree and get the ListView.  Assuming there is only one ListView parallel to the Button, something like this should work ...

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var par = (sender as Control).Parent;
    var gri = (par as Grid);
    if (gri != null)
    {
        foreach (var c in gri.Children)
        {
            if (c is ListView)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do it by naming convention.  Name your button "BlahButton" and that will mean that "BlahListView" is the parallel list view.  You could also use a general hook like [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.tag.aspx).